# planar 1-in-3 sat described as a planar graph for independent set

Tags: reductions, 3-sat, planar-graphs, polynomial-time-reductions

Given a planar 1-in-3 sat formula, can someone reduce that formula into a graph that asks the question when ever there is an independent set for it, that's also planar?

Comment: Every graph has an independent set...

Comment: I should clarify. The Graph should represent the planar 1 in 3 sat and the independent set of that graph should represent the solutions to my planar 1 in 3 sat formula

Comment: What does it mean for a graph to "ask a question"?  Can you [edit] the question to state the problem more clearly?  What is the input, and what is the desired output?  You might need to use several sentences to define your concepts carefully.  Don't put clarifications in the comments; instead, [edit] the question so it can be understand by someone reading it for the first time, without reading the comments.